# CSS 3 not selector for print media

Tags: css, printing, css-selectors

I am trying to print a part of my entire html document. I am using the below css to do that.

```
@media print { body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#print-area * {
   visibility: visible;
}}
```

It is working but as visibility:hidden reserves the space, it is printing a blank page and my content. I was trying to use :not selector from css3 to set all other divs but "print-area" to display:none as below,

```
div:not(#print-area){ display:none; }
```

This will result into a print of blank page. Looks like :not selector is not working with media print. Any suggestions/solutions for this will be most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: would setting the rule as !important work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visibility: hidden;` holds the space and it is hidden only. Show use `display: none;` to your body.

```
@media print { #wrapper {
    visibility/: hidden;
    display: none;
}
#print-area {
   visibility/: visible;
   display: block;
}}
```

**Edit** you should also declare for screen

```
@media screen { #wrapper {
         display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But once i apply display:none to body*, it will hide everything in the body including the print-area, hence cannot really do it.

Comment: yet another recommendation: don't use body * but define your whole container in a div then do `body yourdiv`

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
:not(#print-area){ display:none; }
```

Comment: Tried this, but for some reason it looks like :not has no effect when it comes to @media print. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Change the style rule for print media to be

```
:not(#print-area){ display:none !important; }
```

It's likely that any standard css reset in play on the page is outranking this style rule.